# Store values in a form created with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a button and onclick of that button, I am creating a popup with input fields in it which is being done with help of AJAX. Once the form is created i am trying to store the values in the form using session.

Here is my ajax call:

```js
function getDiskSheet() {
  var form = document.getElementById("Form");
  var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater("output",
    "/jsp/Limiter.jsp", {
     asynchronous : true,
     postBody : Form.serialize(form),
     method : 'post',

     onComplete : function() {
      displayLimiter();   
     }

    });
 }
```

```html
<td class="trigger_popup">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1"><input type="button" value="open form" onclick="getDiskSheet()"> </a>
```

This is what my form looks like.

[image: popup form]

The issue here is that everytime i close the form and click on the button again, it re-runs the ajax function and the data entered previously disappears. I am trying to find a way to save the data in the form and reopen it with previously entered data.

I don't need to enter it in the database so i am trying to store it using session but it's not working for me.

Here's what i tried. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
 <%
    String save = request.getParameter("save");
    if(save != null){
        String[] diskvalues = request.getParameterValues("diskvalues");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("diskvalues", diskvalues);    
    }

    %> 

<%
    String diskvalues = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("diskvalues");                
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, and of course if the information can be stored (avoid senstive information) you can use the Javascript Localstorage:

Example:

```
String[] diskvalues = //here you get your diskvalues;

window.localStorage.setItem('diskvalues',diskvalues);
```

And then you retrive it in this way:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('diskvalues');
```